# Disable automatic screen changes to another

Tags: windows

How to disable the windows screen automatically switching to another. Means, while I am typing something in word, the window automatically changes to another when some thing like pop up message, application lock happens in that window. It is annoying. How to change that setting?

Comment: Is it always a certain program? Is this on a desktop or laptop? Is a new program starting up or only open programs? What happens if you close all other programs while typing in Word?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow those pop-ups there is no way to stop them from having focus. You will have to disable them in the program they are from.